# loaded web page content store in variable

Tags: javascript, xml, variables

i am try to load web page content in to div:-

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js" ></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function load(){
                        var location = "http://services.gisgraphy.com/geoloc/search?lat=43.00034713745117&lng=-75.4999008178711&radius=7000";
                                    $("#siteloader").html('<object data="'+location+'">');
                        }
        </script>
    <body onload="load()">
    <div id="siteloader"></div>​
    </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

with this code done to load web page content into div now i want to store this content in to one `variable` any idea how its possible....

Comment: Not possible due to same origin issues. Load it on the server and process it there. But since it is a web service, why do you not load the data using that service?

Comment: Like this geocoding/geocode?address=108%20avenue%20des%20champs%20elysees%20paris&countrycode=FR&outputformat=json

Comment: @mplungjan no not this type i want to content which is display in div tag